# Can't require_once fdpf/fpdf.php

Tags: laravel, fpdi

I am using the FPDI library from JanSlabon for securing PDF file uploads from my laravel app. But I can't execute the code require_once even though I navigated to the file itself. I am getting the error:

```
Failed opening required '../../vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.4/share/php/pear')
```

My require code is:

```
require_once('../../vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('../../vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the libraries are already located in your vendor folder, you should simply make use of the autoload.php file of composer (doesn't laravel uses this by default?).

So just add the dependencies to your composer.json (if not already done):

```
"require": {
    "setasign/fpdf": "^1.8",
    "setasign/fpdi": "^2.2",
    "setasign/fpdi-protection": "^2.0"
}
```

Update via `composer update` and:

```
<?php
use setasign\FpdiProtection\FpdiProtection;

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$pdf = new FpdiProtection();
...
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly after also adding base_path() to the require_once cuz for some reason laravel cant find my vendor folder

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I am getting an error of "Call to undefined method setasign\FpdiProtection\FpdiProtection::FPDF()" when using the method "$pdf->FPDF('P', 'in', array('6','9'));" been looking for solutions for a while now :(

Comment: Why would you call the constructor that way? `$pdf = new FpdiProtection('P', 'in', array('6','9'));` should do the job?

Comment: Ahhh I see now sorry I am new to coding... I managed to output and created a encrypted pdf but once I use the method "->Output($fileName, 'F')" it generates the pdf but it generates it in the vendor folder, is there a way to change this path?

Comment: The `$name` parameter can also be a path, sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your relative path `../../` to vendor is probably wrong.  To avoid this issue, use the Laravel `base_path()` helper which will provide an absolute path.

```php
require_once(base_path('vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php'));
require_once(base_path('vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/autoload.php'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can autoload using `composer.json`. First of all, create a directory called **Custom** in **app** directory and copy **fpdi** directory to `app/Custom`.

Now in `autoload` section of your composer.json file, require the file. After requiring the file, your composer.json file's autoload block should look like this if it is a fresh Laravel app:

```php
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/Custom/fpdi/FPDI_Protection.php"
    ]
},
```

After updating your composer.json file, run `composer dumpautoload`. Now you can utilize the classes in your Laravel controllers or models without requiring the files manually.

While doing tests, I see that this library uses some deprecated methods and so on. You will have to deal with it, i.e. update the code to suite your needs. But I hope that this answer will help you in a way that you will be able to use any other library as well. Do a Google search and find a more modern library if this one's fixes are too broad.

Comment: All packages are available through packagist/composer so there's nothing to load manually.

Comment: @JanSlabon That's not true. A lot of old and rare code pieces are not available via packagist and sometimes you need to manually load certain libs.

Comment: For sure with "all packages" I mean the packages that were used/needed by the author.